# Can't Push Commits to Central Repository

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have done everything that the youtube tutorial shows to do at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JByfXdbVAiE .  Everytime that I go to push to origin the process hangs and will eventually fail.

The output that I am getting is this:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe push "origin" master:master
(Then it hangs here for 20 minutes plus)

I am able to clone the central repository, I am able to pull from it, I am committing changes to my personal repository but it will not allow me to push.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/[repository]
  Push  URL: https://github.com/[repository]
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

I am not honestly sure what that all means.

```
$ git push origin master
Username:
Password:
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while acces
lordcheeto/iGEM-DNA-Processor.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Checked and rechecked to make sure I was entering the right information.

**EDIT 2:**

When I went to manage my origin remote in Git Extensions I loaded my ppk SSH key and when I tested the connection I received:

```
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
```

I am guessing that it is my ISP so I am checking with them unless anyone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

The remote may not be set up correctly. If I were you, I would just go and do that from the command line.

See if your remote is setup for pushing:

```
git remote show origin
```

You should see whether the branch is set up for that. If you get an error at this point, you have to check that your ssh keys are setup correctly. Whichever site you are using to push to, there are instructions in the support section on how to do that.

If it is, test it with:

```
git push origin master
```

Let us know how it goes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here's what I got.


  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)

It is a public repository so I was thinking that anyone should be able to push.  Thanks again.

Comment: The repository is at: https://github.com/lordcheeto/iGEM-DNA-Processor

I plan to delete the link once the problem is resolved.  (Found out stackoverflow doesn't do PM s)

Comment: change your urls in the .git/config file to the SSh format. I've never had issues with that. Also, when you generated your ssh keys, did you provide a password?

Answer (score 1):

An old question I know, but I just had this problem.

You need to use the **SSH** remote url, not the **HTTP** one:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add your public key to GitHub?

Comment: Crap! Might need to add you as a collaborator to have write access...but you still didn't have the public key in there, so not all my fault.